# node-schedule not working with express.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, node-modules

I am trying to get node-schedule working with express.js with not luck

I'm not sure why this is not triggering ?

here is my code

```
var schedule          = require('node-schedule');

var rule = new schedule.RecurrenceRule();
rule.minute = new schedule.Range(0, 59, 5);


schedule.scheduleJob(rule, function(){
    console.log(rule);
    console.log('Hi---------------------------');
});
```

Answer (score 1):

```
var rand = require('randomstring');    
var jobId = rand.generate(10); //randomsrting
var at = new Date();
var time = at.setSeconds(at.getSeconds() + Number(5))  //after 5 second     
schedule.scheduleJob(jobId, new Date(time),function(){
     schedule.cancelJob(jobId);
     console.log('hi--viral');
 });
```

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, this does work

I hadn't waited long enough

Comment: this should be a comment